# JavaFX to executable .jar file

Tags: java

I have finished making my JavaFX application and i want to package it and send it to the user. However, when I go to the "Clean and Build", a blank selection box of available classes is displayed. I have about 10 Jframe forms and a main class. i also attempted to create a Preloader class but still there is no class being displayed in the Available classes. Is there anyway to work around this, I am using Netbeans 8.0 IDE and Java SE Development Kit 7 update 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rClick Project -> Project properties -> Build -> Deployment -> tick Enable native packaging;

*Clean and build Project*

rClick Project -> Package as -> image only

Then check

```
  dist/bundles
```

Comment: also... your main class should extend Application; and have a main(String[] args) method.

Comment: When i try that, i run into the following errors java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
 at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
 at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.copyFile(IOUtils.java:50)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never had that error. You should post it in a different thread.